# How to specify account in new Google SignIn 8.3.0

Tags: android, google-api-client, google-signin

I believe this question applies to pretty much all the android applications that use Google Sign-In.

I've implemented Google Sign-In as recommended here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

But when I ask user to approve/deny my permissions as

```
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

it first shows account selector with a button to Add Account.

I'm 100% sure that if a user has only 1 account, they would use it. How can I avoid that extra dialog and extra click?

I can get all the accounts using AccountManager, and check if there's only one. But how to tell Sign-In to use it?

Answer (score 2):

After reverse-engineering GoogleApiClient, I found that it has `setAccountName()`. It doesn't work with Sign-In, but Sign-In has it's own `setAccountName()` in GoogleSignInOptions.
And voila! It works (make sure to revokeAccess() to invalidate previous sign-in token).
So here's what I ended up with:

```
// If there's only one account on device, we're 100% sure user would use it.
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
if (accounts.length == 1) {
    String accountName = accounts[0].name;
    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(gso)
            .setAccountName(accountName)
            .build();
}
```

Hope that helps anyone.